# Is it possible to create an Android Service to handle custom APN to fix ICS limitations?

Tags: android, service, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application working on Android 2.3 very well, but my client is planning to upgrade his devices to Android 4.0.4 soon.

Their devices have a custom firmware with my software inside. The application creates automatically a custom APN and have other features.

I have two limitations in ICS: The program does not run if users does not start it manually and I can't create custom APN because the permission was removed from Android.

I was thinking to create a new application (a service) to create the APN and change the old application to call this new one.

The new one will be signed with the same certificate of the firmware. Reading some posts, if your software is signed with system certificate, you can create APN's. Is this right?

Another question: This new service, obviously does not have an interface, so users will not start it manually once. Can I write an application to start it?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to know the answer: you need to use the system certificate and put your software into the firmware.